# Power Supply change for ceiling fan controler

Tags: electrical

I currently have a 110v ceiling fan with a speed control switch. Is it possible to change the power supply to 220v? If possible, do I need to change the control switch only? Thanks.

Comment: This is very unclear.  You want to change the supply voltage why?  What about the fan, is that remaining the same or will that change?

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: technicaly possible, but I don't know of any off-the shelf product to do this.

Answer (score 2):

The motor would need to have been manufactured to allow for the voltage change, which is not common for household ceiling fans. If it was, it would be labeled for that inside where you make the connections.

If your idea is that the fan will use less energy at 220V, that is a false notion. The current will be lower but with the higher voltage, the power (kW) will remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Normally speed controllers are voltage specific so I would doubt that you could change from 120 to 240.
Why would you want to try this is there a reason you want to try this?
In most cases I would say No this cannot be done, if it is done because the controller can handle the voltage the motor cannot. 
So the answer would be NO.